# Django new attribute not up showing in admin dashboard after making migrations

Tags: python, mysql, django

Just some context: I took over my live website from my developer recently, I have some basic coding knowledge but I'm not very proficient.

I tried adding a 'purchase_type' attribute to the Product model, but the new attribute is not showing up in the admin dashboard even after making migrations. When I query the database however, the attribute is there and returns the right value.

### 1. Added 'purchase_type' to models.py:

```
class Product(models.Model):

index_number = models.IntegerField(default=None, blank=True, null=True)
name = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
coming_soon = models.BooleanField(default=False)
retail_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=100, decimal_places=2, default=None, null=True)

calories = models.IntegerField(default=None, blank=True, null=True)
protein_class = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
carb_class = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
fat_class = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
purchase_type = models.CharField(max_length=500, default="Subscription")
```

### 2. Added 'purchase_type' into the fieldsets in admin.py:

```
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
list_display = ("name", "index_number", "coming_soon", "retail_price", "calories", "protein_class", "carb_class", "fat_class")
search_fields = ("name",)
list_filter = ("protein_class", "carb_class", "fat_class")
ordering = ("index_number",)
fieldsets = (
    ("Main Info", {
        "fields": ("index_number", "name", "coming_soon", "retail_price", "calories", "protein_class", "carb_class", "fat_class", "purchase_type"),
    }),
```

### 3. Ran the following commmands in running order:

```
./manage.py migrate
./manage.py makemigrations webapp
./manage.py migrate
```

### 4. When I query the database for purchase_type, the correct value is returned:

```
./manage.py shell
from webapp.models import Product
>>> print(Product.objects.values('purchase_type'))
[{'purchase_type': u'Subscription'}, {'purchase_type': u'Subscription'}, {'purchase_type': u'Subscription'}, {'purchase_type': u'Subscription'}]
```

### 5. However, the admin dashboard does not have the attribute or value:

[purchase_type not showing admin dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iw4vl.png)

### 6. Here are the database settings in settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': 'lpdb',                                     # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        # The following settings are not used with sqlite3:
        'USER': '[redacted]',
        'PASSWORD': '[redacted]',
        'HOST': 'localhost',                                # Empty for localhost through domain sockets or '127.0.0.1' for localhost through TCP.
        'PORT': '',                                         # Set to empty string for default.
    }
}
```

Thank you very much for helping and have a great day!

### Edit: Here's the full admin.py file

```
from webapp.models import Subscription, Product, MailingListSignup
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from import_export import resources
from import_export.admin import ExportMixin

class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ("name", "index_number", "coming_soon", "retail_price", "calories", "protein_class", "carb_class", "fat_class")
    search_fields = ("name",)
    list_filter = ("protein_class", "carb_class", "fat_class")
    ordering = ("index_number",)
    fieldsets = (
        ("Main Info", {
            "fields": ("index_number", "name", "coming_soon", "retail_price", "calories", "protein_class", "carb_class", "fat_class", "purchase_type"),
        }),
        ("Macronutrients", {
            "fields": ("protein_amount", "protein_units", "net_carbohydrates_amount", "net_carbohydrates_units", "sugars_amount", "sugars_units", "dietary_fiber_amount", "dietary_fiber_units", "fats_amount", "fats_units", "saturated_fats_amount", "saturated_fats_units", "monounsaturated_fats_amount", "monounsaturated_fats_units", "polyunsaturated_fats_amount", "polyunsaturated_fats_units"),
        }),
        ("MVitamins & Minerals", {
            "fields": ("sodium_amount", "sodium_units", "sodium_percentage_dv", "potassium_amount", "potassium_units", "potassium_percentage_dv", "calcium_amount", "calcium_units", "calcium_percentage_dv", "iron_amount", "iron_units", "iron_percentage_dv", "iodine_amount", "iodine_units", "iodine_percentage_dv", "zinc_amount", "zinc_units", "zinc_percentage_dv", "selenium_amount", "selenium_units", "selenium_percentage_dv", "magnesium_amount", "magnesium_units", "magnesium_percentage_dv", "vitamin_a_amount", "vitamin_a_units", "vitamin_a_percentage_dv", "vitamin_c_amount", "vitamin_c_units", "vitamin_c_percentage_dv", "vitamin_d_amount", "vitamin_d_units", "vitamin_d_percentage_dv", "vitamin_e_amount", "vitamin_e_units", "vitamin_e_percentage_dv", "vitamin_k_amount", "vitamin_k_units", "vitamin_k_percentage_dv", "b2_riboflavin_amount", "b2_riboflavin_units", "b2_riboflavin_percentage_dv", "niacin_amount", "niacin_units", "niacin_percentage_dv", "b1_thiamine_amount", "b1_thiamine_units", "b1_thiamine_percentage_dv", "vitamin_b6_amount", "vitamin_b6_units", "vitamin_b6_percentage_dv", "vitamin_b12_amount", "vitamin_b12_units", "vitamin_b12_percentage_dv", "folates_amount", "folates_units", "folates_percentage_dv", "pantothenic_acid_amount", "pantothenic_acid_units", "pantothenic_acid_percentage_dv", "biotin_amount", "biotin_units", "biotin_percentage_dv"),
        }),
    )
    save_as = True

class SubscriptionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ("user", "user_phone_number", "stripe_customer_id", "stripe_subscription_id", "stripe_successful", "paid_amount", "shipped", "datetime_ordered", "stripe_email", "shipping_name", "shipping_address_country", "shipping_address_zip", "shipping_address_state", "shipping_address_line1", "shipping_address_city", "shipping_address_country_code", "monthly_qty", "calories", "protein", "carb", "fats")
    search_fields = ("user", "datetime_ordered")
    list_filter = ("user", "datetime_ordered")
    ordering = ("datetime_ordered",)

class UserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    list_display = ('username', 'email', 'is_staff', 'date_joined', 'last_login')
    ordering = ('-date_joined',)
    list_filter = ('date_joined', 'last_login')

class MailingListSignupAdmin(ExportMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email')
    search_fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email')

admin.site.register(Subscription, SubscriptionAdmin)
admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
admin.site.register(Product, ProductAdmin)
admin.site.register(MailingListSignup, MailingListSignupAdmin)
```

Comment: Show us the contents of the `admin.py` in your app?

Comment: Do you get any error in `console` for your browser?

Comment: @solarissmoke I've added it in

Comment: @iamhssingh I don't get any error messages in the browser console

Comment: restart everything

Answer (score 0):

You try few things:

First you have to look-up in your migrations folder to check if the `Purchase_type` has been included in your migrations file or not.

If **yes**, then run this command, which will undo all your migrations :

```
python manage.py migrate webapp zero
```

To redo your migrations run the 2 commands below to makemigrations and then migrate and check if it solves your problem.

---

If **NO**, then delete all your migration files from **`App`**and re-run:

**Delete all files having numericals ahead of them**
**`App` > Migrations > 0000_files.py**

```
python manage.py makemigrations webapp
python manage.py migrate
```

---

If this doesn't solve your problem, then delete your `dbsqlite3` file and make migrations again. This always helps but you'll have run all the migrtions, superuser creation, etc..

---

**Update**

Run this command:

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

This command will implement the changes in your models file to your PostgresSql database.

Comment: I've tried all of the suggestions, except for deleting the dbsqlite3 file. The issue still isn't resolved. I don't have a dbsqlite3 file, seems like another database is being used. I've included the database settings in the main post.

Comment: You use postgres, okay. So i presume youre using **PgAdmin**  as a db Admin?

Comment: @mrccb91 I have update my Answer, kindly have a look.

Comment: Hi, I ran the syncdb command, the attribute still doesn't turn up in the admins page. I reverted to the previous migration, ran the migration again and then ran the sync for good measure - still the same